# Left joining with NAs

Tags: python, pandas, join

I have a following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'proj': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C'],
    'country': ['POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'USA', 'FRA', np.NaN],
    'date': ['2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-09-01', np.NaN],
    'feature_proj': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 106, 106, 106, 106, 106, 110],
    'feature_country': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, np.NaN],
    'feature_date': [1000, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, 1009, 1010, np.NaN]
})
```

[image: first df to join]

which I would like to join with:

```
forecastFor = pd.DataFrame({
    'proj': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D'],
    'country': ['POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'GER', 'POL', 'USA'],
    'date': ['2018-07-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-11-01'],
    'hours': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
})
```

[image: second df to join]

in a way so that at the end I would get:

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({
    'proj': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
    'country': ['POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'POL', 'USA', 'USA', 'GER', 'POL'],
    'date': ['2018-07-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01'],
    'hours': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    'feature_proj': [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 106, 106, 106, 110, 110],
    'feature_country': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN],
    'feature_date': [np.NaN, 1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007, 1008, np.NaN, np.NaN]
})
```

[image: expected after join]

So, I have a dataframe (`data`) with features on different levels. There are project-level features, there are project&country-level features and there are project&country&date-level features. I also have a second dataframe (`forecastFor`) which containes some value per project-country-date tuple (named here `hours`). I want to join these two so that:

- in the result I have the same records as in `forecastFor` but with added feature columns. There should be no additional records but records may be removed if there is no match for the `proj` column
- the join should be of `inner` type for the `proj` column - they should all match and all non-matching records should not be included in the result
- the match on `country` and `date` should be of `left` type (pandas removes the records with NA in columns on which the join is done but I still want the records with matching `proj`, even when the `country` is NA)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry it was a simple thing, after writing down the question I instantly figured out the answer:

```
projLevelFeaturesData = data[['proj', 'feature_proj']].drop_duplicates()
countryLevelFeaturesData = data[['proj', 'country', 'feature_country']].drop_duplicates().dropna()
dateLevelFeaturesData = data[['proj', 'country', 'date', 'feature_date']].drop_duplicates().dropna()
projJoined = forecastFor.merge(projLevelFeaturesData, on=['proj'], how='inner')
countryJoined = projJoined.merge(countryLevelFeaturesData, on=['proj', 'country'], how='left')
joined = countryJoined.merge(dateLevelFeaturesData, on=['proj', 'country', 'date'], how='left')
```

Comment: Mark as answered even if it's your own

Comment: well this requires three separate joins. Maybe someone else will come up with a better answer using some pandas magic

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.merge(forecastFor, data, how='left')
```

gets you close...

````
0   A   POL 2018-07-01  1   NaN NaN NaN
1   A   POL 2018-09-01  2   100.0   1.0 1001.0
2   A   POL 2018-10-01  3   100.0   1.0 1002.0
3   A   POL 2018-11-01  4   100.0   1.0 1003.0
4   A   USA 2018-09-01  5   100.0   2.0 1004.0
5   A   USA 2018-10-01  6   100.0   2.0 1005.0
6   B   POL 2018-06-01  7   106.0   3.0 1006.0
7   B   USA 2018-07-01  8   106.0   4.0 1007.0
8   B   USA 2018-08-01  9   106.0   4.0 1008.0
9   C   GER 2018-10-01  10  NaN NaN NaN
10  C   POL 2018-11-01  11  NaN NaN NaN
11  D   USA 2018-11-01  12  NaN NaN NaN```
````

Comment: you output is not the same as expected output

Answer (score 0):

You could just get columns of `forecastFor` that has `proj` in `data` before joining left like this:

```
forecastFor=forecastFor[forecastFor['proj'].isin(data.proj.unique())]
df=forecastFor.merge(data, on=['proj','country','date'], how='left')
```

OUTPUT

```
   proj country        date  hours  feature_proj  feature_country  \
0     A     POL  2018-07-01      1           NaN              NaN   
1     A     POL  2018-09-01      2         100.0              1.0   
2     A     POL  2018-10-01      3         100.0              1.0   
3     A     POL  2018-11-01      4         100.0              1.0   
4     A     USA  2018-09-01      5         100.0              2.0   
5     A     USA  2018-10-01      6         100.0              2.0   
6     B     POL  2018-06-01      7         106.0              3.0   
7     B     USA  2018-07-01      8         106.0              4.0   
8     B     USA  2018-08-01      9         106.0              4.0   
9     C     GER  2018-10-01     10           NaN              NaN   
10    C     POL  2018-11-01     11           NaN              NaN   

    feature_date  
0            NaN  
1         1001.0  
2         1002.0  
3         1003.0  
4         1004.0  
5         1005.0  
6         1006.0  
7         1007.0  
8         1008.0  
9            NaN  
10           NaN
```

Comment: you output is not the same as expected output